# Equals() not returning true for two equal strings

Tags: java, string, function, character-encoding, equals

I have failed to find the reason why the two strings are not equal.Here is my code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
       JTextArea jt=new JTextArea();
        jt.append("why \n me?"); //i set a test value to the JTextArea
        Document doc = jt.getDocument();
        Element root = doc.getDefaultRootElement();
        Element element = root.getElement(0); 
        int start = element.getStartOffset();
        int end = element.getEndOffset();
 //the code above is what i specifically need for my app, to bring a 
 //specific line from a JTextArea
        String s;
    try {
        s=doc.getText(start, end - start);
   System.out.print("s = "+s);

       if(s.equals("why")) //i expect equals() here to return true
        System.out.print("s equals "+s);
       else
        System.out.print("s is not equal to "+s);

    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
        ex.getStackTrace();
    }         
 }
```

The result I get after running the program is:

```
 s = why 
 s is not equal to why
```

Comment: `"why "` is not equals to `"why"`

Comment: In your program s="why \n"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result must have a space as you have a space before the new line

```
 s=doc.getText(start, end - start);
```

You `end` is including the space before `\n`. You need to write

```
 s=doc.getText(start, (end -1) - start);
```

Or you can trim it while comparing as it is just space. *Note that if you have someother letter other than space trim wont work.*

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that the `s` string is actually `"why "`.  Note the space character.

Indeed, if you look at the string you append to the JTextArea, there is space after "why" and before the newline.

---

Generally speaking, when you display a string for debugging purposes, it is a good idea to display it with quotes around it so that can notice any leading or trailing whitespace.  For example:

```
       System.out.println("s = '" + s + "'");
```

---

Another possible explanation (though unlikely in this case) is [homoglyphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoglyph); i.e. two different Unicode codepoints that *look like* each other in a typical font.

Answer (score 0):

If you print it out with eye catcher: `System.out.print("s = >>" + s +"<<");`

you see that at the end you have included the blanks and the line break:

```
s = >>why 
<<s is not equal to why
```

and `why \n` is not equals to `why`
use `s = doc.getText(start, end - start).trim();` and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to compare the content of two string object,you can use `s.compareTo("why")==0`